# Get remote hardware info without authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, hardware

I would like to know if there is a way to get remote HW/SW information like hostname,manufacturer and model of a server/desktop which running any linux based OS without submitting authentication info. I already tried with `SSH` and `dmidecode` commands but they need to provide root password for that.

**Edit** I need to get above mentioned info without facing a security check (an authentication step) I tried to get the info via `ssh ip_address dmidecode -t system` but I have to face a authentication step when I use that method. I read in windows using `wmi services` I can do that. is there a similar implementation for Linux based systems.

Comment: You should explain in more detail what you are looking for. Otherwise this is something like a _guessing_ game.

Comment: @arkascha I have edited my question. can you look into it. thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your edit just repeats what you already wrote before. Question: what is the problem with an authentication? Certainly it makes sense that you cannot request system details "just like that" from outside a system. I don't see a reason why such authentication should keep you from doing whatever you want to do...

Comment: @arkascha I want to write a script which runs against a given ip range and and returns their host name if there are any for a ip inthat range. I want to skip the authentication because there can be many usernames and passwords withing that ip range. so providing authentication info for each and device in that range will be a hectic task.

Comment: As said before: there is a reason why you can't. It would be a major security gap if you could. There is a reason for authentication. If you are allowed to use the systems, then you would create a unique account for that task and your problems would be solved. Since you don't we have to assume you are trying to spy on systems you have no access to. Nothing against healthy research spirit. But I simply don't know such a general service offering such information.

Answer (score 0):

I see several variants:

1. send this info **from** each computer (i. e. by cron)
2. publish info over http protocol
3. write script with SUID flag and take access to user with empty password (I dislike this way by security reasons)

I think there are more other variants

Comment: I can't do modifications to remote end since they are not modifiable. I'm looking for solution which I can implement in local side and connect to remote end to only get the information I need.

Comment: With this refinement I'm affraid you can't do it. You should get this info as superuser or modify remote side